# Autologin functionality in swift

Tags: swift, autologin, uiscenedelegate

I want to implement Autologin functionality. when i will open my app it will go to "loginViewController".And after login i am saving the login id to UserDefaults.And for the second time if UserDefaults has the value the ift will go to "SlideMenuController". i have written the code in "sceneDelegate". The code is-

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let logId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loginId")  {

        goToPlayerMenu()
    }
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}


func goToPlayerMenu() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PlayerHomeScreen", bundle: nil)

    let homeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerHomeViewController") as! PlayerHomeViewController

    let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlayerMenuViewController") as! PlayerMenuViewController

    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
    nvc.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
    nvc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    nvc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    nvc.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    //menuViewController.homeViewController = nvc
    let slideMneu  = SlideMenuController.init(mainViewController: nvc, leftMenuViewController: menuViewController)
    slideMneu.delegate = homeViewController as? SlideMenuControllerDelegate
    slideMneu.changeLeftViewWidth(UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40)
    slideMneu.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMneu

}
```

Now i want to go to Login viewcontroller, if i will logout of the app. But as my rootViewController is "slideMneu". i am unable to go to the "loginViewController". is there any option to go to the "loginViewController" after logout?

my logout function is-

```
func logout(){
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "customer_id")
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "isContributor")
            FUser.logOutCurrentUser { (logout) in
                if logout == true{
                    print("DEBUG: Logout completed")
                }

            }
            let Alert = UIAlertController(title:Common.sharedInstance().TITLE_ALERT, message:Common.sharedInstance().CONFIRM_ALERT, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let OKButtonAction = UIAlertAction(title: Common.sharedInstance().ALERT_YES, style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let LoginViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LoginViewController!, animated: true)
                //                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            let Cancel = UIAlertAction(title:Common.sharedInstance().NO, style: .default, handler: nil)

            Alert.addAction(OKButtonAction)
            Alert.addAction(Cancel)

            self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

All codes comes from my project

1.Where you set you Keywindow RootViewController

```
let navigator = Container.shared.resolve(INavigator.self)!
let localStorageService = Container.shared.resolve(ILocalStorageService.self)!

// if you store login user key or not
if localStorageService.isKeyExist(key: Configs.KEY_USER) {

    // if there is key,then goes to main page
    navigator.switchRoot(keyWindow: window!, scene: .main(viewModel: MainTabBarViewModel()))
} else {
    // there is no key,then goes to login page
    navigator.switchRoot(keyWindow: window!, scene: .intro(viewModel: IntroViewModel()))
}
```

2.Login Page
by calling Api,you can get a token(key) from api,and this token is highly customizsed by backend developer.please store this token(key) in user default.

3.You will need this token later whenever you need to call some authorised API in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the initialization for `window`, which can be fixed like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    if let logId = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loginId")  {
        goToPlayerMenu()
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Frankenstein after logout i want to go to "LoginViewController". i have edited my question. i have added the logout function. please look into it.

Comment: Wasn't your initial question to set `rootViewController`? You shouldn't be modifying the question to ask a new one. If you have another question it'd best to create a new post and add the link below and I'll surely take a look and help you out.

Comment: no my question is same. only i have added the logout function

Comment: and my question is about autologin implementation